# How do I Grab Selected Index on two Dropdownlist's OnSelectedIndexChanged?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to use two DropDownLists to filter data.  I set both of the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` Equal to the method below. The problem is it is only grabbing the `SelectedIndex` of the DDL that is changed. Example: if i choose a option in DDL1 it grabs that value and doesnt grab the value of DDL2. They both have the same `OnSelectedIndexChanged` i figured it would grab the current value of both. Is there a way to make it look at both DDL Controls?

```
 protected void BrandsList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    int DDLcatId = CategoriesList.SelectedIndex;
    int DDLBraId = BrandsList.SelectedIndex;

    IQueryable<Product> DDLprodResult = GetProductsDDL(DDLcatId, DDLBraId);

    if(DDLprodResult == null)
    {

    }

    else
    {
       CatLab.Text = DDLprodResult.ToList().Count().ToString();
       productList.DataSource = DDLprodResult.ToList();
       productList.DataBind();
    }
 }
```

Comment: That is because at a time only 1 of the 2 dropdowns can be selected which will trigger the event. Try selecting an item from 2nd dropdown and you will see that it triggers the event as well.

Comment: I want to pass both selected items as a param? So i am asking how can i grab both?

Comment: Your code should work. Of course only one can be changed if you have set `AutoPostBack="true"`(default is false) on both. But you should get the correct `SelectedIndex` anyway.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I love and hate that at the same time. If i select one it only grabs 1 of the two values depending on the dropdownlist i use.

Comment: @TimSchmelter i think my first options is being looked at as 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work. Of course only one can be changed if you have set `AutoPostBack="true"`(default is false) on both. But you should get the correct `SelectedIndex` anyway in the handler.

So i will guess: you are databinding the `DropDownLists` on every postback. Do this only `if(!IsPostBack)`, otherwise you always overwrite changes with the original values.

So for example in `Page_Load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EvengtArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        // DataBind your DropDownLists
    }
}
```